# Gaussian process regressor - same std-deviation for all the values sklearn 0.23 version

Tags: scikit-learn, regression, prediction, gaussian

Q1) I using Gaussian process regressor on sensor data to estimate human pose. while predicting on the test data I am getting std deviation same for all the values. Is it normal to get standard deviation same as I have used Standscaler() for scaling the data.

Q2) Secondly, I want to improve my score on test data, currently it performs poorly with score 0.27.
whenever I am trying to use mixture of kernel my process gets stuck and never returns. Any suggestion, how to resolve this issue.

Below is the code.

```
scaler_x = StandardScaler()
scaler_y = StandardScaler()

stance_train = scaler_x.fit_transform(stance_train)
stance_label = scaler_y.fit_transform(stance_label)
stance_test = scaler_x.transform(stance_test)
stance_test_label = scaler_y.transform(stance_test_label)
kernel = RBF(length_scale=3.0, length_scale_bounds=(10,1e-02))
gpr1 = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel, random_state=0, n_restarts_optimizer=500, normalize_y=True, alpha=0.01).fit(stance_train,stance_label)

res1 = gpr1.score(stance_test, stance_test_label)
print(res1)

mean, sigma = gpr1.predict(stance_test[:1], return_std=True)
print(sigma)
[0.10220269 0.10220269 0.10220269 0.10220269 0.10220269 0.10220269
0.10220269 0.10220269 0.10220269 0.10220269 0.10220269 0.10220269
0.10220269 0.10220269 0.10220269 0.10220269 0.10220269 0.10220269]
print(mean)
[[-0.32279146 -1.36695596 -0.09067824 -1.46859509 0.71355078 0.76069065
-1.32083008 0.13645212 -0.13363496 -0.12042919 0.65796758 0.04662945
-0.7011215 -1.28839211 -0.17705824 0.37084057 -0.46027648 0.33293756]]
```

Comment: Hi. Can you try running your model with different length scales perhaps with `length_scale=1.0` and `length_scale=0.1`? Do you see the same behaviour with these different parameters?

Comment: @balleveryday : Thanks for your reply. Yes, I have tried with different length scales but it didn't work. Also, the number of data points I am passing are around 23,000 and features are 18 (the input shape is (23417,18)). Do you think this Gaussian process can converge over this much of data?

Comment: So all different scales gave the same standard deviation? I don't think the GP would have a problem to converge in fact in Chapter 2.5 of the [gaussian processes book](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW2.pdf) the authors use a similar dataset.